# force app to refresh image (from URL)

Tags: refresh, image, reload

I have an image in my app (android) taken from an URL:

```
<img src="URL"/>
```

If i change the image on the server (keeping the same URL), the app does not refresh and keeps always the old image.

How can i force the app to reload/refresh the right image (always on the same URL)?

(the app is written with jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appending a querystring to the image url with a random number that you change each time you display the image.

This may for example be done with javascript.

```
<img id="myImage" src="URL"/>
<script>
 var newRandomNumber = (new Date()).valueOf();
 var img = document.getElementById('myImage');
 img.src += "?random=" + newRandomNumber;
</script>
```

This script will get the html element with the id myImage and append a querystring parameter which will (hopefully) force a reload of the image.

(NB the value (new Date()).valueOf() in the code is not random but a number that represents the current time)

Hope this helps!

Comment: i try.
I need only to put this ?random=newRandomNumber in the html code?
Can you explain me how it works? 

(sorry i'm really a beginner)

Comment: I have reworked the answer to include a javascript that appends a parameter to the url.

Comment: The idea is to send the "random" parameter which will "trick" the client to think that it is not the same image that is requested and that the cached image can't be used. The server, on the other hand, will ignore the parameter and just send its current version of the image.

Comment: One question...why it works only for one image?
if i try the same javascript in other link, in the same page or others, with different images and url, it does not work

Comment: ...! Solved. My fault, i didn't change a var.
It's perfect.